# Cannot Get MySQL Cluster to Install Correctly

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

So, I'm trying to install MySQL Cluster with 6 data nodes (All CentOS 7.0 Core Install), 2 SQL nodes (All CentOS 7.0 Core Install), and a management node (CentOS 7.0 Core Install). On all servers, I ran the following commands after downloading the RPM packages

```
yum -y install MySQL-Cluster-shared-gpl-7.4.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm perl-Data-Dumper
yum -y remove mariadb-libs
yum -y install MySQL-Cluster-server-gpl-7.4.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

All these commands ran successfully with no errors or warnings.

The next step for me is to configure my SQL nodes using mysql_secure_installation, but when I run the command, I get the following error message

```
Can't find a 'mysql' client in PATH or ./bin
Cleaning up...
Warning: Could not unlink .my.cnf.9299: No such file or directory
Warning: Could not unlink .mysql.9299: No such file or directory
```

I've tried different things, looked all over Google and I cannot find a fix for this, has anyone ever ran into this issue?

Comment: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/40606.  It can't find mysql where it should be or where you've defined where it should be (PATH).  I don't know if this "fix" works for a cluster since it's for one instance of a mysql installation.

Comment: I actually got it to work... It was an issue with the amount of RAM I had... Kinda strange.

Comment: What a weird error message for that type of problem.  Glad you got it fixed though.